# Play multiple youtube embed videos simultaneously (the "actual" video, not just starting buffering)

Tags: youtube-api

I would like to know if it's possible to start multiple embed youtube videos (on the same page) at the exact same time (taking in account the buffering which is different for each video) 
I'm aware that it may sounds silly and the purpose of this is to synchronise the audio tracks for all the videos.

Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 1):

I think you could synchronize the start with some hack, but then you could not ensure that reproduction is simultaneous, because it may vary the loading speed of each one of the videos

This page contains a good discussion of how to use and synchronize the player events:

http://eduniverse.org/how-sync-web-page-events-embedded-youtube-videos